# How to check the progress of the Gradual site Delete Timer job

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-foundation, timer-jobs, site-deletion

We have one large content database, consisting of two site collections with 250 GB space .

We have deleted one large site with 100 GB size from content database using gradual site delete job.

The gradual site delete job is running every day and running just for 1 to 2 minutes.

The Job history is showing it is running on the desired content database where our deleted site was hosted,  but ending within 1 to 2 minutes .

Noticed that unused space in content database is increasing and the content database table rows are getting changed.

Before Deletion: 
Alldocs - 17112725
AllLinks - 15537151
NameVluePair - 16992586
storagemetrics - 17112723
alluserdata - 1678086
doctostreams – 5867519

After deletion table with rows.

Alldocs - 1570168
AllLinks - 7728077
NameVluePair - 8
storagemetrics - 1570168
alluserdata - 1375680
doctostreams - 2553731

Note--content database is hosting another site with 100GB data.

how we can  confirm whether this job is running and deleting the site content with complete data of 100 GB  from content database?
How long it will take to completely delete the content.

Answer (score 2):

Below explanation should answer your query:

> When a site collection is deleted, the site collection entry (pointer)
>   in dbo.SiteMap is removed from the configuration database and from
>   dbo.Sites in the corresponding content database. For all purposes of
>   user access to the site collection Url or its content the site
>   collection no longer exists and is inaccessible, or otherwise, the Url
>   is no longer reserved.
>
> The site collection deletion is then queued into a new table
>   (dbo.SiteDeletion) in the hosting content database where it is marked
>   to be gradually deleted.
>
> At this point in the operation, a new Timer Job Definition [Gradual
>   Site Delete] executes on a daily schedule [configurable], and will
>   continuously attempt to delete all the data for all the site
>   collections in its queue (dbo.SiteDeletion). It will delete the data
>   in small enough batches of a maximum of 1000 rows through multiple
>   transactions to avoid lock escalation, and can be resumed in the event
>   any failure occurs so that it can attempt the delete process again if
>   needed.  Once the site collection is fully deleted the
>   dbo.SiteDeletion entry is removed.

Considering that your content DB space is 100GB it should take more time since the job is performing delete operation in small batches.

Reference : https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/wbaer/2010/08/02/gradual-site-delete-in-sharepoint-2010/